Best practice on oracle composite index
I have a table calculation(id,client,date,type,amount,company,sales...)
I have a query with where condition on date=? and type=?
The column type can have only 3 values:A,B and C (with 85% of values are A,10% B and 5% C)
What is the best order when creating a composite index :(date,type) or (type,date)?
(If my query is filtering on type=C, is it better to have index(type,date) so that the type will already filter out 95% of rows)

Oracle doesn't evaluate indexes in column order (as if there were a tree on top of a tree), it only follows its single binary tree sorted by that column order (the "concatenated" value of those columns). It's true that if you narrow down your results earlier in the column order you may have a couple fewer branch block I/Os, but those are usually insignificant compared with leaf node scanning I/O which won't differ based on column order, and even that is massively dwarfed by the single block table I/Os that happen for each ROWID. The optimizing of a binary search to reduce the # of hops it makes is of miniscule importance compared with these other factors. You really don't get a noticeable difference in performance merely by swapping columns if you have an equality predicate on both columns.
For concatenated index column order, what matters most is query patterns, not cardinalities. We don't know your query patterns other than the one example you've given. If there are other possible queries I suggest (type,date) because you are unlikely to always place an equality predicate (=) on a date column. If the index started with date and you did a non-equality predicate (<, >, between, etc.) on it, you'd loose the ability to seek on any subsequent column (type). If you had other queries that filtered on date only, then of course you'd want an additional index on date alone, though a skip-scan with only three values in the leading column would be pretty efficient even without adding this second index.
If, on the other hand you know that you will almost always use an equality predicate (=) on the date column, then it doesn't make a noticeable difference either way. However, since you are likely to issue a query that filters on date but not on type, in this scenario you may consider (date,type) simply to not have to create two indexes and let one index serve both purposes.


What is the best order when creating a composite index :(date,type) or (type,date)?

Since the query is using equality to search in both columns, it doesn't matter which one is first or second. This is a seek type of index search, rather than a range scan index access.

If my query is filtering on type=C, is it better to have index (type,date) so that the type will already filter out 95% of rows)?

No index will be useful for the predicate type=C. A full table scan is probably optimal in this case, since there are only three values in that column.
